# Where can I find the information for an Elemental Myrmidon for use in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e

As a DM(GM) I use a battle mat and miniatures for the majority of my encounters. Having recently made the switch to 5e I am not overly familiar with all of the monsters or resources at my disposal. I have checked the main wizards page and the Internet to the best of my ability and have been unable to find any information on Elemental Myrmidons that I can use for the miniatures that I have procured.

Answer (score 10):

Elemental Myrmidons are creatures specific to the Elemental Evil campaign, and are detailed in the book for that campaign, *Princes of the Apocalypse*. You can buy it on Amazon or from your FLGS.